# How can I print my default gateway using Python? This line is giving me an error: print(ifcfg.default_interface())

Tags: python, default, gateway

He is the whole code:

```
import ifcfg
import json

for name, interface in ifcfg.interfaces().items():
    # do something with interface
    print (interface['device'])       # Device name
    print (interface['inet'])         # First IPv4 found
    print (interface['inet4'])        # List of ips
print(ifcfg.default_interface())
```

When I removeprint(ifcfg.default_interface()) the program runs fine.

Here is the error message I get:

Traceback: File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\IFCONFIG.py", line 15, in 
print(ifcfg.default_interface())
return Parser(ifconfig=ifconfig)._default_interface(route_output=route_output)
AttributeError: 'WindowsParser' object has no attribute '_default_interface'. Did you mean: 'default_interface'?

Answer (score 0):

From what I was able to gather this is a **Windows** specific issue. Ifcfg class **WindowsParser** currently has no method _**default_interface**.
You can try and write your own here's the path.

```
C:..\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ifcfg\parser.py
```

For reference here's the **UNUX** version of _default_interface in **parser.py**

```py
    def _default_interface(self, route_output=None):
        """
        :param route_output: For mocking actual output
        """
        if not route_output:
            out, __, __ = exec_cmd('/sbin/route -n')
            lines = out.splitlines()
        else:
            lines = route_output.split("\n")

        for line in lines[2:]:
            line = line.split()
            if '0.0.0.0' in line and \
               'UG' in line:
                iface = line[-1]
                return self.interfaces.get(iface, None)
```

Alternatively use interfaces() this is generally sufficient for most users.

```py
import ifcfg
import json

for name, interface in ifcfg.interfaces().items():
    # do something with interface
    print (interface['device'])       # Device name
    print (interface['inet'])         # First IPv4 found
    print (interface['inet4'])        # List of ips
    
print(ifcfg.interfaces())
```

Further reading: https://github.com/ftao/python-ifcfg/issues/25